# After updating to android studio 3.3 the apk that is built with android studio not working

Tags: android-studio

I have updated my android studio and after that, I have a kind of problem which will encounter when I want to install the APK with Android-studio. When I hit the play button The app builds successfully but it won't install on my ( or any ) device(s) not via ADB nor from manually putting the APK on the device then installing it.

I have tried building it from the command line `gradlew assembleDebug` and it works, it builds an APK and when I put it on the device it gets installed. I have turned off Experimental `Only sync the active variant` that was no good. I have changed my compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28 that was no good either.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. Thank you for your time.

## Update 1

I have deleted `.gradle` folder in the user directory, re-installed the Android-studio, deleted the `.idea` folder and `.gradle` folder in the project directory but no luck still can't install the app after building.

## Update 2

if I install the app by `adb install app-debug.ak` the result is:

`adb: failed to install app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]` ( Note: This is with `adb` in the terminal and nothing have to do with Android-studio )

And I can install it with flag `-t`

## Update 3

[image]
This is the run tab after building the app and Trying to install.

## Update 4

I have un-installed Android studio and then re-installed it from an installer still the problem exists.

## Update 5

There is a blinking Emulator in my `Select Deployment target` named: `emulator-5554 [OFFLINE]` And when it is trying to install I think it has to do something with this.
[image]

Comment: Does your app contains in app purchase? If it is, here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191524/android-gradle-appcompiledebugaidl-input-length-1/54191560#54191560

Comment: There is no app purchase in my app.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html

Comment: @Luksprog It was working before I updated the Android-studio. now it isn't. Why? My previous version was 3.2.1

Comment: @AmirEbrahimi Make sure your minSdkVersion is lower than the sdk on your device.

Comment: @AliAli I'm sure. my device is android O. and my minSdkVersion is 19 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I installed my windows again and it started working.